# Comma between two subjects in a sentence

Tags: commas

The title of an article on CNBC is "Republicans, Democrats spar over gun regulation after Texas school shooting". Is it correct to use a comma between Republicans and Democrats. Together they form a compound subject, so should an and be used instead?

Link to article:
https://www.cnbc.com/2022/05/29/republicans-democrats-spar-over-gun-regulation-after-texas-school-shooting.html

Comment: It's not really "correct". It's ***headlinese***, replacing the syntactically-expected conjunction ***and*** with a comma to save space. I'm not 100% certain, but I think it's probably also "ungrammatical" to discard the definite article before *[**the**] Texas school shooting*. Don't waste time trying to understand the syntax of headlines until you have a good understanding of "normal" contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - thank you. I agree that "the" is needed, because the sentence is referring to a particular shooting.

Comment: Don't get too committed to the idea that the article is "required" simply because it's *referring to a **particular** shooting*. Consider, for example, *I usually just veg out on the sofa after a big meal. But after [**the**] Christmas dinner last year, I went for a nice long walk*. The article there is entirely ***optional*** even though obviously it's a *very* "particular" reference (and I seriously doubt anyone could make a solid case for the *meaning* being affected by whether or not the article was included).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I see the point. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should we use comma instead of "and" between two names.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/268153/when-should-we-use-comma-instead-of-and-between-two-names) Also [Using a comma instead of "and" in "A and B are the objects that are part of the equation."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/301104/) and ["comma" or "and" between section names?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/296578/comma-or-and-between-section-names)

Comment: ...I imply no criticism of you for not finding those earlier questions. Things like that aren't easy to find unless you already know what you're looking for. (*And* the built-in search facilities here aren't very good - but I knew enough to do a Google site-specific search for **headlinese comma instead of and** :)